# jQuery - selector for opening first level folder in 3 level folder structure

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, css-selectors

I've a 3 level folder structure created in Angular 5 as below

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let content of contents">
          <tr class="top-row">
             <td class="parent"><i id="parentFolder" class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>{{content.title}}</td>
           </tr>
       <ng-container *ngFor="let subFolder of contents['subfolder']">
           <tr class="object-row">
             <td class="child"><i id="childFolder" class="fa fa-folder-open"></i>{{subFolder.title}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let product of subfolder['innerFolder']">
              <td class="secondchild"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>{{product.title}}</td>
            </tr>
       </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

I'm currently able to toggle open all folder under top-level as with below `jQuery` selector

```
$('.parent').click(function () {
      $(this).parent().nextUntil('.top-row').slideToggle(10, function () { });
}
```

this opens both `child(firstlevel)` & `secondchild(secondlevel)` to slide open, my requirement is to open only the `child(firstlevel)` folders

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

- First use `.parents('table')` to select the table parent
- If you have multiple parent tables, use `.first()` to select the first one
- Use `.find('.child')` to select the children with the class '.child'.

Example:

```
$('.parent').click(function () {
 $(this).parents('table').first().find('.child').slideToggle(10, function () { });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/om7cpawy/

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code:

```
$('.parent').click(function () {
      $(this).closest('.top-row').slideToggle(10, function () { });
}
```

This code will only work on the closest parent tag with `top-row` class. Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: this toggles off the parent folder & displays only the child & inner child folders